# Simple issue with Jquery - Make Array to Mulitple chose

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to JQUERY and Jscript, and I have to do a simple thing that I'm sure that the solution is simple, but all my searches have got nothing, and I'll glad to get help.

The thing that I need is just to get specific value from an array list by click the specific row.

For example at this code, there is array of "people" and I want that when the user will click at specific row the var "myValue" will get the correspond value. It's for doing a multiple choice.

For example if the user will click "Moshe" value will be = "Moshe", or if he click "Izhak" the value will be assign to "Izhak".And so on.

Please help ,Thanks in advance.
The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- My question -->
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="windows-1255">
    <title>Draft2</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Hi</h1>

    <div id = "test"></div>




    function myFunction(){ 
        window.alert("function"); 
    } 
    var people=["Avraham","Izhak","Yaakov","moshe","aaron", "Yosef","david"]; 
    var length = people.length; 
    function displayPeople(){ 
        for( i=0; i <length; "+people[i]); 
            } 
            } 
            displayPeople(); 
     //trying to get the specific value by clicking

      $("#test").click(function(){  
        var myValue = $("#test").text(); 
        window.alert(myValue); 
    }); 
    //$(document).ready(function(){ // displayPeople()});
```

Comment: `for( i=0; i Hi "+people[i]); ` - was that an error when copying/pasting your code??

Comment: For your explanation/description to make sense you may want to share your HTML.

Comment: yeah I was problem with editing. it's need to be i<length.

Comment: And I trying to put the html, don't succeed

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, there are 2 different issues with your code:

1. display all names in the "people" array into a html table
2. when clicking on a table row, get its element id

To achieve first goal, you can iterate the array and append each item to your root html tag.

To achieve second goal, you should bind the "click" event to the DOM element you are interested on.

Example:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>

<script>
var people=["Avraham","Izhak","Yaakov","moshe","aaron", "Yosef","david"];
var length = people.length;

function displayPeople(){ 
     for(i in people)
        $("#myTable").append('<tr><td data-people-id="'+i+'">Hi '+people[i]+'</td></tr>');
}

displayPeople();

// get the specific value by clicking
$("#myTable").on("click","tr td",(function(){ 
    var myValue = $(this).data("people-id"); 
    window.alert(people[myValue]); 
})); 
</script>
```

JS fiddle demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/ogoqnurr/

Comment: Wow great man God bless u. it's work.
But if I want just part of it. for example if it's full names, like Avraham Cohen, Izhak Levi and so on, and I just want the primary name? How I take that?

Comment: And why I needed two vars? peopleId and myValue - one enogh , not?

Comment: sure, sure. With just peopleId or myValue is enough. I've updated the answer.

Comment: And if I want just part of the word it's complicated ?